# Preciso relacionar 3 tabelas no laravel, alguem ajuda!!! Ja tentei de todas formas!

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relacionamento

Eu tenho 3 tabelas

Vendas

```
ID | TITULO
```

Corretores

```
ID | NOME
```

Relas - "Faz o relacionamento entre as tabelas"

```
ID | VENDAS_ID | CORRETORES_ID | TIPO
```

Preciso que a tabela `relas` faça o relacionamento entre as tabelas

Tentei na minha model relas assim :

```
  public function vendas()
    {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Vendas::class);
    }

    public function corretores()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Corretores::class);
    }
```

Minha model vendas assim:

```
  public function relas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Relas::class);
    }
```

Minha model corretores assim:

```
 public function relas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Relas::class);
    }
```

E minha migration RELAS assim:

```
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger("vendas_id");
    $table->unsignedBigInteger("corretores_id");
    $table->string("tipo");
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign("vendas_id")->references("id")->on("vendas")->cascadeOnDelete();
    $table->foreign("corretores_id")->references("id")->on("corretores")->cascadeOnDelete();
```

Só que nao estou conseguindo fazer o relacionamento, pois uma venda tem varios corretores e varios captadores, por causa disso que precisei fazer uma tabela separada de relacionamento, alguem me ajuda?

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi direito acho que o que você precisa é da relação [HasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through).

No vendas teria:

```
public function corretores()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough(Corretores::class, Relas::class);
}
```

No corretores seria:

```
public function vendas()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Vendas::class, Relas::class);
}
```

Assim você conseguirá pegar os corretores de uma venda e vice versa.